# CustomAction : Put JavaScript code in a dedicated file

Tags: javascript, custom-actions

I have a custom action that look like this :

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="MyCustomAction" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        ...
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="MyCommand"
          CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello World!');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

How can I move the `alert('Hello World!');` JavaScript code from the custom action definition to a dedicated `MyScript.js` file ? (in the `_layout` folder or any other place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can wrap it in function declared in you file:

```
function MyFunction()
{
    alert('Hello World!');
}
```

And then call it in the same way:

```
CommandAction="javascript:MyFunction();"
```

As for JS file you can add it to Layouts folder and create a delegate control to render link to this file in the page. You can deploy such delegate control in the same feature as your Ribbon customization.

Answer (score 2):

To use the dedicated js file add another customaction with Location=ScriptLink in the xml file, like:

```
 <CustomAction Id="ITIdea.Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.TaskCompletedButton.Script" Location="ScriptLink" ScriptSrc ="/_layouts/ITIdea/ScriptSource.js"/>
```

In the script file define your own functions and use these in the CommandAction like Alex showed already.

Comment: Be aware that if your custom action registered by feature, it would load `ScriptSource.js` in ALL site pages, even admin ones.